# VS 2013 MVC two separate project must share the same model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have two separate projects in Visual Studio Web 2013 (of MVC type) which must share the same database model.

How can I do this?

I ask because if I ever make a change in the database structure, my model will change and the other model may remain unchanged.

This is the case of a web application that has two parts: one is the user part and one is the administration part. I am forced to separate them for security reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice is making model classes in a separate project. The remaining projects will only refer to the assembly model And All changes will be only in the project models
(**ObjectModule** contains database entities, **MyProject** 
only a reference to **ObjectModule**)

[image]